# merge 2 google chart dataTables to 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, join, datatable, google-visualization

i have 2 google chart dataTables that i want to merge to 1 google chart dataTable.

example table 1:

1 | test1 | 20

2 | test2 | 30

---

example table 2:

1 | test1 | 20

3 | test3 | 60

---

i want to merge the 2 to:

1 | test1 | 20

2 | test2 | 30

3 | test3 | 60

what is the best way to do that? 
my code now does not combine them but just adds the rows and colums. 
docs: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#join

```html
oldjson = '
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]}
      ]
}';

newjson = '
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]}
      ]
}';


var oldData = new google.visualization.DataTable(oldjson);
var newdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(newjson);
console.log("old data", oldData);
console.log("new data", newdata);

// i want to merge the 2 datas here
var mergedData = google.visualization.data.join(oldData, newdata, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

console.log("merged data", mergedData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given the example tables provided in the question,

you would want to use a `'full'` join, with `keys` for all columns

leaving the options for `dt1Columns` and `dt2Columns` empty

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y1', 'y2'],
    [1, 'test1', 20],
    [2, 'test2', 30],
  ]);

  var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y1', 'y2'],
    [1, 'test1', 20],
    [3, 'test3', 60],
  ]);

  var joinData = new google.visualization.data.join(
    data,
    data1,
    'full',
    [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]],
    [],
    []
  );

  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(joinData);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

assuming the data tables always have the same number of columns
(as each other)

and the join type will always be the same

you can build the `keys` dynamically using a loop

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y1', 'y2'],
    [1, 'test1', 20],
    [2, 'test2', 30],
  ]);

  var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y1', 'y2'],
    [1, 'test1', 20],
    [3, 'test3', 60],
  ]);

  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    keys.push([i, i]);
  }

  var joinData = new google.visualization.data.join(
    data,
    data1,
    'full',
    keys,
    [],
    []
  );

  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(joinData);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: yes it does thanks! but how to make it more dynamic? because i dont always know the amount of columns

Comment: thanks :) still working out an error i get from it jsapi_compiled_format_module.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.map called on null or undefined

Comment: fixed it ( made a mistake in the json ) thanks for your help WhiteHat

Comment: Im trying to do something different now, and still having trouble because of the lack of documentations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066254/google-chart-append-datatable-rows-to-other-datatable