# Google chart can you split up array in another way?

Tags: google-visualization

As far as I have seen it this is the way to make a line chart is like this in Google Charts:

```
        data.addRows(
    [
        // change strings to Dates (year, month), where months are zero-indexed
        [new Date(2013, 0), 5, 2, 1],
        [new Date(2012, 11), 2, 0, 2],
        [new Date(2012, 10), 5, 1, 3]
    ]);
```

The above will make three lines.....line 1: 5->2->5, line 2: 2->0->1 and line 3: 1->2->3. This is not logical for me. I would like to make a line like this....line 1:

```
            data.addRows(
    [
        // change strings to Dates (year, month), where months are zero-indexed
        [new Date(2013, 0), 5],
        [new Date(2012, 11), 2],
        [new Date(2012, 10), 5]
    ]);
```

And then line 2:

```
                data.addRows(
    [
        // change strings to Dates (year, month), where months are zero-indexed
        [new Date(2013, 0), 2],
        [new Date(2012, 11), 0],
        [new Date(2012, 10), 1]
    ]);
```

etc. My example is wrong. But I hope you get what I mean to do - and you can find a way to make a more DB-friendly query. The reason is also that my dates will differ. So I would need a long array with lots of nulls in it.

Well I hope you can help me :)

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42003644/5090771)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.....I am not too strong at javascript, but it certainly looks like a solution! Thanks again.